# React: Why can't I pass data from one functional component to another functional component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am a bit lost as to why I can't pass fetched data between two functional components. I tried to use Hooks and it returned an error message suggesting to use array for object[Promise]. Any idea what I missed here? I'm pretty new to React. Any help would be appreciated!

```
// Component A
function App() {
  const apiURL = "https://services9.arcgis.com/M4Su6cnNT6vqupbh/arcgis/rest/services/COVID19_Data/FeatureServer/0/query?where=1%3D1&outFields=*&outSR=4326&f=json";
  const apiData = fetch(apiURL)
                    .catch(err=>console.log(err))
                    .then(data=>console.log(data));
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello</h1>
      <DataVisualize data={apiData}/>
    </div>
  );
}

// Component B
function DataVisualize(props){
    return <div>{props.data}</div>;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `apiData` does not contain the actual data you want - it's only a Promise. Its `catch` is also in the wrong place (put the `.catch` *after* the `.then`s), and you need to call `.json` or `.text` on the Response (returned by the resolve value of `fetch`) in order to get a Promise that resolves to the actual data you need.

Set some state when the final data is retrieved instead:

```
// Component A
function App() {
  const apiURL = "https://services9.arcgis.com/M4Su6cnNT6vqupbh/arcgis/rest/services/COVID19_Data/FeatureServer/0/query?where=1%3D1&outFields=*&outSR=4326&f=json";
  const [data, setData] = useState();
  useEffect(
    () => {
      fetch(apiURL)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(setData)
        .catch(console.error); // handle errors
    },
    [] // run this only once, on mount
  );
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello</h1>
      { data && <DataVisualize data={data}/> }
    </div>
  );
}

// Component B
function DataVisualize(props){
    return <div>{props.objectIdFieldName}</div>;
}
```

Also note that the result doesn't appear to have any `.data` property (though it does have a `objectIdFieldName` property, so I put that in as an example).

Comment: Hi, thank you for your thorough explanation. I wasn't clear in my question. The url returns json data. do I still need to use res.json()? This is another part I was confused.

Comment: Yes. `fetch` resolves when the response *headers* are received, and then you need to wait for *another* Promise for the response *body* to be completely received.